# I lost my top left panel in unity. How can I get it back?

Tags: 11.04, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

I messed around with the compiz setting to set up desktop cube when I first installed 11.04.  Big mistake right?  I have everything back to normal but my top left panel is gone and I have tried everything to get it back.  Unity --reset usually hangs on me and nothing else I have seen in the forums works.

Comment: The Unity launcher?, is that what you referring to?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the Compiz settings for unity with a terminal command: `unity --reset`

Comment: I have tried that a bunch of times.  It always hangs and forces me to hard reboot.  Also, doesn't fix anything.

Comment: How about resetting all of the Compiz settings: `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1 && unity --reset`

Comment: The reset does not work unless the plugin is actually enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Unity plugin enabled in CCSM? Oh and when I tried the cube, it screwed up things for me as well. Try using the Desktop Wall instead.

This thread might be relevant as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/35949/unity-sidebar-gone-black/47407#47407

Comment: Unity plugin is enabled.  I tried both unity --reset and unity --reset-icons

Comment: Neither of those reset commands worked for my problem earlier. Check the answer I left to the linked question if it helps you.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the problem? If yes, then answer your own question so it may help others.